# Configure ActiveMQ to producer only

Tags: activemq-classic, consumer, producer

I have the following configuration. The server listens to incoming ActiveMQ messages from producers that run on clients. I want to avoid from a client to create a consumer. Otherwise any client can sniff to all messages on bus and this is serious security flaw. Is there anyway to restrict clients to create only producer?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ feature different security options to control access on a fine grained level.

You typically want to use the authorization plugin.

For instance, if you have a queue `Queue1` that user `sputnik` should produce to and user `apollo` should consume from, you can setup the authorizationPlugin like this:

```
<authorizationPlugin>
       <map>
         <authorizationMap>
           <authorizationEntries>
             <authorizationEntry queue="Queue1" read="apollo" write="sputnik" admin="admin" />
```

- Read:  Consume
- Write: Produce
- Admin: Create

You can create authorization entries like queue=">" that maps to every queue, or a prefix with queue="SECRET.>"

Ensure you have authentication enabled to use these features.